# Show different color when click on bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I believe it's very simple thing, but still suffering...

I simply need to change color on the header part of boostrap accordion, when user collapse it. 
So when accortion part is collapsed, I want to have different header color than rest of the accordions headers, and when user click on another header, this one get's "back to normal color" and another collapse and change color.

Now, what it does, that when I click on it, it colapses and nicely changes color, however when I click again, it have the same color so I have to click again, collapses again, but it gets back to default color, even when it's collapsed.

I've tried to test many things, but still didn't get a proper result.

Thank you :)

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"> 
              <div class="panel-header">
                321
              </div>
            </a>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
     <div class="panel-opened-area">
          123
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .panel-header {
        background: #fff;
        color: $dark;

 .active-time {
        background: #707070;
        color: #fff;
      }
```

jQuery:

```
$('#accordion > .panel').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.panel-header').toggleClass("active-time");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem, I think I found a solution. [Look Here](https://jsfiddle.net/leonardoaraujocosta/L52ubxou/).

I have helped in some way

```js
$('#accordion .panel').on("click", function() {
  $(this).siblings().find(".panel-heading").removeClass("panel-heading-active");
  $(this).find(".panel-heading").toggleClass("panel-heading-active");
});
```

```css
.panel-heading-active {
  transition: all .5s;
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-active" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
              raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
              raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
       <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
       </a>
      </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
              raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tested your code and it works much better than any of my results. However, as my panels are - after page loads - collapsed, the effect not working correctly. 
So, when I load the page, despite that panel is inmidiatelly collapsed, it doesn't have changed color. I must first click on it and than it changes. 
Thing is, that when I click on it, it works VICE VERSA.
I mean that I click on panel, it collapse and it has normal color, than I click back, panel closes and it has changed color. 
Can you also help me with that ? Much appriciated :)

Comment: I propably need something which will react more on actuall state of panels, rather than click method

Comment: @JZK I think I understand your problem. I made some small changes in the case of HTML that I left on the link at the beginning of the post. (The code is presented here is not exactly running into problems with JQuery. Please check the link at the beginning of the answer).

Comment: Im sorry for later reply. 
Yes, now your code works exactly as I need. 
I've updated my code, so now it work better, but not in the way I need it. 
Now, when I load the page, first panel is collapsed, but the header have normal color. When I click on any other panel, it collapses and changes color as I need...
so problem now is that when I load page, first collapsed panel has still normal color. 
Can you pls explain me what changes you have made in HTML ? Really cant see the important parts there, as Im using different code on my page. I want to implement only importand part. 
Thank you)

Comment: Oki, it's working :) 
Three minutes later ... hihi...
Thank you again!!!